# com.google.firebase.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.Date in koltin/android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image: image description here]

I use cloud firestore!

I was unable to solve this problem. 
I get this error:

> com.google.firebase.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.Date

but I think the converter I have already created inside Adapter.
the pictures you see all the details of the code

Comment: please post your code instead of posting a link to the image.

Comment: image description here  :: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICyUC.jpg  ==> is link clickable

Comment: yes link is clickable but most of us view the question by looking at the content. also the link may become invalid ( if hosted elsewhere) at any point in the future. so its always good to post the relevant code and the error in your post itself by editing it. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please, post your code as text, with minimal reproducible code required

Answer (score 1):

try out the following code if you want timestamp

```
val timestamp = data[TIMESTAMP] as Timestamp
```

and if you want date object from timestamp

```
val date = timestamp.toDate()
```

Comment: you mean I have to change the code inside mainActivuty?

Comment: yes, inside main activity where you are reading data from hash map

Answer (score 0):

The answer above has got the right idea but you need to change it a little.
You need to cast it as a firebase timestamp for it to work.

```
val timestamp = data[TIMESTAMP] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
val date = timestamp.toDate()
```